# How can I edit this JSON file with bash script and jq

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, json, jq

I have config.json file with the following content:

```
[{
  "host0": "11.11.11.11",
  "host1": "22.22.22.22",
  "host2": "33.33.33.33",
  "host3": "44.44.44.44",
  "host4": "55.55.55.55",
  "host5": "66.66.66.66"
}]
```

and I'm trying to create a .sh bash script that can be launched from command line and edit that config.json file to completely remove the whole host0 line along with its value. Then I need the remaining values to "move up" -- I mean rename host1 to host0, host2 to host1, host3 to host2, host4 to host3, etc etc, but their values should stay same. The end result should look like this:

```
[{
  "host0": "22.22.22.22",
  "host1": "33.33.33.33",
  "host2": "44.44.44.44",
  "host3": "55.55.55.55",
  "host4": "66.66.66.66"
}]
```

How can I do it with bash script and jq, or any other method with bash script launchable from command line or/and cron? Hardcoding in .sh script like *jq '.host0 = "22.22.22.22" config.json* is not an option; I need the script to read config.json and copy values from host1 and paste it to host0 and so on.

Comment: Why isn't the JSON just using a simple object like `{"hosts": ["11.11.11.11", "22.22.22.22", ...]}`?

Comment: How are you maintaining `hosts` (sort) order ?

Answer (score 4):

The following `jq` expression applies the transformation to each element of the top-level array (you only have a single element in that array in the question).  The transformation involves building a new array from the given keys and values by replacing the value of the most recently added key+value with the value for the element being added to the end.  This creates an array of length `n+1` (where `n` is the number of keys and values in the original array element) where the first value is the value that should be discarded, `11.11.11.11` in the question, and where the last key is the key that should be discarded, `host5` in the question.  With `.[1:-1]` (which could also be written `del(first,last)`) we discard the first and last elements and are left with a list of `n-1` keys and values.

```bash
jq 'map(to_entries | reduce .[] as $a ([{}]; last.value = $a.value | . += [$a]) | .[1:-1] | from_entries)' file
```

Here's the `jq` expression on its own, in an easier-to-read format:

```
map(
  to_entries |
  reduce .[] as $a (
    [{}];
    last.value = $a.value |
    . += [$a]
  ) |
  del(first, last) |
  from_entries
)
```

Given the following JSON document in `file`,

```json
[
  {
    "host0": "11.11.11.11",
    "host1": "22.22.22.22",
    "host2": "33.33.33.33",
    "host3": "44.44.44.44",
    "host4": "55.55.55.55",
    "host5": "66.66.66.66"
  },
  {
    "server0": "Atlantis",
    "server1": "Gotham",
    "server2": "Rivendell",
    "server3": "Asgard",
    "server4": "Hogwarts",
    "server5": "Neverland"
  }
]
```

... the `jq` command would produce the following:

```json
[
  {
    "host0": "22.22.22.22",
    "host1": "33.33.33.33",
    "host2": "44.44.44.44",
    "host3": "55.55.55.55",
    "host4": "66.66.66.66"
  },
  {
    "server0": "Gotham",
    "server1": "Rivendell",
    "server2": "Asgard",
    "server3": "Hogwarts",
    "server4": "Neverland"
  }
]
```

Note that there is no interpretation of the key or value strings.

Answer (score 3):

If [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) is allowed:

The idea beyond this, it's there's already a dedicated language to parse [json](/questions/tagged/json) as *built-in* aka
[**JavaScript** Object Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation) =)

```
#!/bin/sh

node -e '
    function renameKey (obj, oldKey, newKey) {
      obj[newKey] = obj[oldKey];
      delete obj[oldKey];
    }
    var j = require("./file.json"); // mandatory ./
    delete j[0]["host0"];
    let count = Object.keys(j[0]).length;
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        let oldv = "host"+(i+1);
        let newv = "host"+i;
        renameKey(j[0], oldv, newv)
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(j, null, 4))
'
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh

node -p '
    JSON.stringify(
        require("./file.json")
        .map(x => {
            let ok;
            for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(x)) {
                if (ok)
                    x[ok] = v;
                ok = k;
            }
            delete x[ok];
            return x;
        })
        , null
        , 4
    )
'
```

Credits for emanuele6 from jq@libera.irc.

##### Output

```
[
  {
    "host0": "22.22.22.22",
    "host1": "33.33.33.33",
    "host2": "44.44.44.44",
    "host3": "55.55.55.55",
    "host4": "66.66.66.66"
  }
]
```

---

Another way, using `rhino`:

```
$ dpkg -s rhino
Installed-Size: 55
[...]
Description: JavaScript engine written in Java
 Rhino is an implementation of the JavaScript language written
 entirely in Java. It is typically embedded into Java applications to
 provide scripting to end users.
Original-Maintainer: Debian Java Maintainers <pkg-java-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Homepage: http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/
```

(hacky way, not to use in production)

```
rhino -e "
function renameKey (obj, oldKey, newKey) {
  obj[newKey] = obj[oldKey];
  delete obj[oldKey];
}
j = $(< file.json); // shell hack to read file without import fs lib
delete j[0]['host0'];
let count = Object.keys(j[0]).length;
for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    let oldv = 'host'+(i+1);
    let newv = 'host'+i;
    renameKey(j[0], oldv, newv)
}
print(JSON.stringify(j, null, 4))
"
```

Comment: Why limit it to `node`, almost any command/file-with-executable-permissions could be used (i.e. `python`, `perl`, `jq` : ) ). Heck, if the only reason to use `node` is unabbreviated JSON, then `java` also makes sense: **Java**Script Object Notation : )  *(I know JavaScript and Java are not the same)*.

Comment: @JonnyHenly note the use of no module/lib at all except NodeJS itself

Comment: ...in other languages, you need to import modules. It's built-in in JS

Comment: : D , *no module/lib at all except [the large runtime library wrapping the C++ V8 javascript engine]*.  You could have wrapped your here string's javascript with html, echo'ed it to a file, `./tmp.html`, then run `google-chrome --enable-logging --v=1 --user-data-dir=temp-dir ./tmp.html`, then `grep <some_unique_delimiter> temp-dir/chrome_debug.log`. Still using `bash` and the V8 engine, but no need for `nodejs`.

Answer (score 3):

Script that uses `jq` and edits the file:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eu

jq '[.[] | to_entries[1:] | map(.key |= sub("(?<n>\\d+)$";"\((.n|tonumber)-1)")) | from_entries]' "$1" > "$1.tmp"
mv "$1.tmp" "$1"
```

Usage:

```bash
$ cat config.json
[{
  "host0": "11.11.11.11",
  "host1": "22.22.22.22",
  "host2": "33.33.33.33",
  "host3": "44.44.44.44",
  "host4": "55.55.55.55",
  "host5": "66.66.66.66"
}]

$ ./script.sh config.json

$ cat config.json
[
  {
    "host0": "22.22.22.22",
    "host1": "33.33.33.33",
    "host2": "44.44.44.44",
    "host3": "55.55.55.55",
    "host4": "66.66.66.66"
  }
]
```

The formatting changes a bit, but that shouldn't be a problem.

If you want to preserve formatting, or would like to use standard unix tools, using `awk` instead of `jq` is also possible, but way less robust:

```bash
awk -F\" 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} $2=="host0"{next} $2~/^host/{$2="host" substr($2,5)-1} 1' "$1" > "$1.tmp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @json = lines[1..*-2]>>.split(/ <[:,]> /, :skip-empty); put qb[\[\{];  \
            @json = join ",\n", ([Z] @json[0..*]>>.[0], @json[1..*]>>.[1])>>.join(":");  \
            .put for @json; put qb[\}\]];'   file
```

I hesitate to write this answer, but seems to me the OP might run into sorting errors. It's great that the `jq` answers already posted appear to maintain the input order, but at least [one StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214293/is-the-order-of-elements-in-a-json-list-preserved) says that's not guaranteed. From [RFC_8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259) :

```
> An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value   
> pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number,   
> boolean, null, object, or array.
```

Above, the Raku code takes a literal approach to the text, reading `lines` into an array while `[1..*-2]` dropping the first and last bracketing lines (adjust this index if your JSON formatter places brackets/braces on 2 lines instead of one). Each line is split on `<[:,]>` a custom character class consisting of colon and comma, and `:skip-empty` empty elements are dropped. In this manner each `@`-array position contains two elements: host and IP.

Brackets/braces are `put` back in separate statements. The `@json` array is `[Z]` "zipped" together, dropping the first "IP" element (via `@json[1..*]>>.[1]` starting from `1..` instead of `0..`. Zipping stops when any item runs out of elements. Finally, colons, commas and newlines are `join`ed back in.

Sample Input:

```json
[{
  "host0": "11.11.11.11",
  "host1": "22.22.22.22",
  "host2": "33.33.33.33",
  "host3": "44.44.44.44",
  "host4": "55.55.55.55",
  "host5": "66.66.66.66"
}]
```

Sample Output:

```json
[{
  "host0": "22.22.22.22",
  "host1": "33.33.33.33",
  "host2": "44.44.44.44",
  "host3": "55.55.55.55",
  "host4": "66.66.66.66"
}]
```

https://raku.org